# ¿Cómo puedo renderizar un for en jinja2 con dos listas al mismo tiempo usando Flask de Python?

Tags: html, python, bucle-for, flask

Estoy realizando una tabla con información traida desde la base de datos con una conexión sencilla desde Python. Además estoy utilizando Flask con Jinja2 para las interacciones con front-end. El objetivo del siguiente código es traer información de la base de datos, modificar un valor solamente de cara al front end y almacenarlo en una variable (el valor modificado) para una posible operación futura con el valor nuevo.

De forma tal que extraigo dichos registros (filas) de la tabla con un cur.fetchall()

```py
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM conceptos WHERE conceptos.conceptoTipo = 1')     #busca la tabla de la DB
data = cur.fetchall() #Obtener los datos de la BD y los almacena en la variable
```

Pero me interesa modificar un valor en específico de cada fila, en este caso, el valor de la columna 9. Y para ello, declaro una lista y utilizo un *for* para recorrer los registros que traigo en data, de la siguiente manera:

```py
x = []
for i in data:
    x.append(i[9]+1) #Simplemente le sumo 1 al valor numérico para verificar el cambio
```

Y por último retorno ambas variables hacia la renderización del html del front end:

```py
return render_template('descuentosBeneficiarios.html', conceptos = data, operas = x) #Aqui se le mandan los datos al HTML
```

Del lado del HTML, utilizo JINJA2 para exponer las variables de forma dinámica en los campos de una tabla de la siguiente manera:

```html
{% for concepto in conceptos %}

<tr>
  <!-- Recorrer Campos de Tabla-->
  <td>{{concepto.0}}</td>
  <td>{{operas}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.2}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.3}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.4}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.5}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.6}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.7}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.8}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.9}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.10}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.11}}</td>
  <td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Y esto, me arroja el siguiente resultado una vez renderizado:
[image: Imagen renderizada. Información dummy, nada es real.]

Desafortunadamente, ambas listas no se recorren al mismo tiempo y no sé cómo lograr que, en este caso, cada valor de la lista *opera* sea recorrido al mismo tiempo que se recorre la lista *concepto* y se pueda imprimir el único que corresponde a cada fila.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de pasarlo a la plantilla lo puedes convertir en una lista de listas. Por ejemplo:

```py
conceptos_operas = list(zip(data, x))
#...
return render_template(
    'descuentosBeneficiarios.html', 
    conceptos_operas=conceptos_opera
)
```

Y usar eso para iterar en la plantilla:

```py
{% for concepto_opera in conceptos_operas %}
  <!-- Recorrer Campos de Tabla-->
  <!-- concepto_opera = (concepto, opera)-->
  <!-- Aplica la presentación que necesites: tr, td,...-->
{% endfor %}
```